# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'source' has already been declared

Tags: javascript

```js
const source = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function removeFirstTwo(list) {
    const [,, ...arr] = list; // Change this line
    return arr;
}

const arr = removeFirstTwo(source);
/* In chrome developer tools this line is giving the error
I mentioned. but it's working on freecodecamp website. */
```

Comment: It is working as expected. It's perfect

Comment: Chrome keeps a history of already declared variables as `const`.

Comment: Probably you entered/copied that code twice in the same session, Until you close the developer tools, all declarations are remembered ...

Comment: You can execute `{ const source = …; … }` in the console to avoid this